# How to query for VM features using WMI class Msvm_SummaryInformation or Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService in C++

Tags: c++, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

This is code snippet from MSFT documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer
The example uses Win32_OperatingSystem and it works fine. I replaced Win32_OperatingSystem with Msvm_SummaryInformation or Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService 
now uReturn returns 0. I tried lot of things none seemed to work
Please help me out or point me to a C++ program using Msvm_SummaryInformation

```
// For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Msvm_SummaryInformation"), // Win32_OperatingSystem
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)                      // ==> This returns 0
        {
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some struggle I got it fully working and here is the working code:
This produces VM - GUID, Name and State. One can use Msvm_SummaryInformation or Msvm_ComputerSystem I prefer Msvm_SummaryInformation as that Class has more detailed info. I used the example and built on it. No more PS for me :)

```
/*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer
*/#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    // L"ROOT\\CIMV2" for Win32_OperatingSystem
    // L"ROOT\\Virtualization\\V2" for Msvm_SummaryInformation

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\Virtualization\\V2"), // Object path of WMI namespace   
        //_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace  
         NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
         NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
         0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
         NULL,                    // Security flags.
         0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
         0,                       // Context object 
         &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
         );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    //cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;
    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\Virtualization V2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       NULL,                        // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                        // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Msvm_SummaryInformation"),
        //bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem where Caption=\"Virtual Machine\""),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(
            WBEM_INFINITE, 
            1, 
            &pclsObj, 
            &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (vtProp.vt != VT_NULL) {
            wcout << " VM GUID : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ElementName", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (vtProp.vt != VT_NULL) {
            wcout << " VM Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"PrimaryOwnerName", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (vtProp.vt != VT_NULL) {
            wcout << " PrimaryOwnerName : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"EnabledState", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (vtProp.vt != VT_NULL) {
            wcout << " EnabledState : " << vtProp.ulVal << endl;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}
```